# What does it mean if a C++ class member parameter doesn't have a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I've seen code like the following, and I'm confused about what it means for foo's parameter to be a `const A &` rather than a `const A<T> &`. I suspected that maybe this meant that the method can take any `A`, but it looks like it implicitly means `A<T>` based on the fact that `a1.foo(a2)` doesn't compile in the below snippet.

Does `A` always mean `A<T>` when it's used for a variable declaration inside a member of `A`? In what specific circumstances does this hold? I see that I can't make foo's return type `A` (compile error: use of class template 'A' requires template arguments). Would most C++ programmers use `A` or `A<T>` here?

```
#include <iostream>

template<int T>
class A {
public:
    void foo(const A &a);
};

template<int T>
void A<T>::foo(const A &a) {
    std::cout << T << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A<1> a1;
    A<2> a2;

    // These compile
    a1.foo(a1);
    a2.foo(a2);

    // This fails to compile because no viable conversion from 'A<2>' to 'const A<1>'
    // a1.foo(a2); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the linked answer, but tldr, within `A<T>`, the name `A` refers to `A<T>` (the specific type, not the class template). So `A<1>::foo` takes an `A<1> const&` and `A<2>::foo` takes an `A<2> const&`. Those are different types.

Comment: I'm still curious about the style issue. Is it good practice to leave out the `<T>` because it's redundant or should it generally be included?

Comment: I would leave it out, except where needed. Otherwise people will wonder why the template parameter is needed here.